# Unable to start receiver AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver: Attempt to invoke method 'android.net.Uri.getQueryParameter()' on a null object

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I recently started getting this crash for my application in production.

Full StackTrace is as following :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getQueryParameter(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2735)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getQueryParameter(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
   at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver.java:31)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2728)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I could reach to the code of `AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver` and it is as follows :

```
package com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Base64;
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.TransportContext;
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.TransportRuntime;
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.TransportContext.Builder;
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.util.PriorityMapping;

public class AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   public AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver() {
    }

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String backendName = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("backendName");
    String extras = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("extras");
    int priority = Integer.valueOf(intent.getData().getQueryParameter("priority"));
    int attemptNumber = intent.getExtras().getInt("attemptNumber");
    TransportRuntime.initialize(context);
    Builder transportContext = TransportContext.builder().setBackendName(backendName).setPriority(PriorityMapping.valueOf(priority));
    if (extras != null) {
        transportContext.setExtras(Base64.decode(extras, 0));
    }

    TransportRuntime.getInstance().getUploader().upload(transportContext.build(), attemptNumber, AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver$$Lambda$1.lambdaFactory$());
}
```

}

I searched the entire codebase-scope and found that This BroadcastReceiver is being used from :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="29" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- Although the *SdkVersion is captured in gradle build files, this is required for non gradle builds -->
<!-- <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/> -->
<application>
    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" >
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.backends.TransportBackendDiscovery"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

I could find that `AlarmManagerScheduler` is triggering this :

```
package com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling;



public class AlarmManagerScheduler implements WorkScheduler {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "AlarmManagerScheduler";
static final String ATTEMPT_NUMBER = "attemptNumber";
static final String BACKEND_NAME = "backendName";
static final String EVENT_PRIORITY = "priority";
static final String EXTRAS = "extras";
private final Context context;
private final EventStore eventStore;
private AlarmManager alarmManager;
private final SchedulerConfig config;
private final Clock clock;

public AlarmManagerScheduler(Context applicationContext, EventStore eventStore, Clock clock, SchedulerConfig config) {
    this(applicationContext, eventStore, (AlarmManager)applicationContext.getSystemService("alarm"), clock, config);
}

@VisibleForTesting
AlarmManagerScheduler(Context applicationContext, EventStore eventStore, AlarmManager alarmManager, Clock clock, SchedulerConfig config) {
    this.context = applicationContext;
    this.eventStore = eventStore;
    this.alarmManager = alarmManager;
    this.clock = clock;
    this.config = config;
}

@VisibleForTesting
boolean isJobServiceOn(Intent intent) {
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, intent, 536870912) != null;
}

public void schedule(TransportContext transportContext, int attemptNumber) {
    Builder intentDataBuilder = new Builder();
    intentDataBuilder.appendQueryParameter("backendName", transportContext.getBackendName());
    intentDataBuilder.appendQueryParameter("priority", String.valueOf(PriorityMapping.toInt(transportContext.getPriority())));
    if (transportContext.getExtras() != null) {
        intentDataBuilder.appendQueryParameter("extras", Base64.encodeToString(transportContext.getExtras(), 0));
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.setData(intentDataBuilder.build());
    intent.putExtra("attemptNumber", attemptNumber);
    if (this.isJobServiceOn(intent)) {
        Logging.d("AlarmManagerScheduler", "Upload for context %s is already scheduled. Returning...", transportContext);
    } else {
        long backendTime = this.eventStore.getNextCallTime(transportContext);
        long scheduleDelay = this.config.getScheduleDelay(transportContext.getPriority(), backendTime, attemptNumber);
        Logging.d("AlarmManagerScheduler", "Scheduling upload for context %s in %dms(Backend next call timestamp %d). Attempt %d", new Object[]{transportContext, scheduleDelay, backendTime, attemptNumber});
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, intent, 0);
        this.alarmManager.set(3, this.clock.getTime() + scheduleDelay, pendingIntent);
    }
}
}
```

I don't understand, why intent.getData() is getting null?

Can someone help me in resolving this crash?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `.getData()` is returning null, you should look where you are adding this data and why the app are not sending it.

You should check nullability in your method:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getData() != null){
      String backendName = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("backendName");
      String extras = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("extras");
      int priority = 
      Integer.valueOf(intent.getData().getQueryParameter("priority"));
      int attemptNumber = intent.getExtras().getInt("attemptNumber");
      TransportRuntime.initialize(context);
      Builder transportContext = TransportContext.builder().setBackendName(backendName).setPriority(PriorityMapping.valueOf(priority));
      if (extras != null) {
        transportContext.setExtras(Base64.decode(extras, 0));
      }

    
 TransportRuntime.getInstance().getUploader().upload(transportContext.build(), attemptNumber, AlarmManagerSchedulerBroadcastReceiver$$Lambda$1.lambdaFactory$());
    }

}
```

Comment: This code is not written by me, it's being used by some internal library.

Comment: Ok, my fault, didn't get that, well, something it's triggering that BroadcastReceiver and it's not adding any data, you should investigate who send this data. For what I see there should be an AlarmManager that is triggering your BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've got the same bug on my app. I cannot figure how to reproduce it, so I've opened an issue on Firebase SDK's Githuib:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2249

Any update on it will be reflected here.